# Is it possible to change the Icons in XFCE trough the Terminal?

Tags: icons, xfce

I can't seem to find a correct way to do this from the Terminal. I've tried with `gsettings` but nothing changes, I also tried with `gconftool2` but again nothing happens.

Does XFCE even support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xfce has its own property store and access functions. What you want to do is:

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/IconThemeName -s elementaryXubuntu
```

There is also the graphical `xfce4-settings-editor` for locating and editing these entries.